Is it possible to write every real function as the sum of an injection and a surjection?
I wrote the following exercise for my students :

Show that the function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto x$ can be written as the sum of two bijections.

Show that the function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto\sin(x)$ can be written as the sum of two bijections.

Show that the function $$\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }x=0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ cannot be written as the sum of two bijections.


Then I asked to myself: is it possible to write every function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as the sum of an injection and a surjection?

Your function $\#3$ works as a counterexample:
$$h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\quad \quad \quad x\mapsto\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }x=0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
To see that, suppose otherwise.  Say that $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ where $f(x)$ is injective and $g(x)$ is surjective.  Since adding an arbitrary constant to an injective or surjective function preserves the relevant property, we may assume that $f(0)=1$ and $g(0)=0$.
Now, $g(x)$ is surjective, so let $x_0$ be such that $g(x_0)=-1$.  Clearly $x_0\neq 0$, so $h(x_0)=0$. It follows that we must have $f(x_0)=1=f(0)$, contradicting the injectivity of $f(x)$.

The same proof works for every non-trivial abelian group $A$. If $a \neq 0$, then $A \to A$, $x \mapsto \begin{cases} a & x = 0 \ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$ is not the sum of an injective and a surjective map $A \to A$.

@MartinBrandenburg  Absolutely.

I don't think the abelian constraint is necessary... I wrote up a short proof in Lean for fun, and it didn't require any commutativity.

@MattD  Yes, I believe you are correct.  Best, in that case, to not try to regularize $f(0), g(0)$, but just to let $f(0)=c, g(0)=1-c$.  Then letting $g(x_0)=-c$ we still see that $x_0\neq 0$ and that $f(x_0)=c=f(0)$ contradicting injectivity.

There is an extensive discussion of this question in a paper in the American Mathematical Monthly:  D. Ullman and D. Velleman (2019), Differences of Bijections, Amer. Math. Monthly, vol. 126 #3, pp. 199-216.  Here is Theorem 16 from that paper:
Suppose that $a$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  If there are finitely many real numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, $\ldots$, $x_n$, and $y$ such that $a(x) = y$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ and $(a(x_1) + a(x_2) + \cdots + a(x_n))/n \ne y$, then $a$ cannot be written as a difference of an injection and a surjection.  Otherwise, $a$ can be written as a difference of two bijections.
This theorem talks about writing the function as a difference of functions, but since a function is an injection or a surjection if and only if its negative is, the answer is the same for sums.

The article is available here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/48662495
